# A word for moving from one website to another

Tags: single-word-requests, internet

Here's the situation: I browse Tumblr, and then I go to, let's say, Youtube. What is the word for the action? The noun? It's not conversion, or click-through, I just move from one website to another. I don't think it is browsing. Browsing is when you surf the web, and I need a noun for the single action of shifting from one website to another.

Mind you, a NOUN is needed. There are many verbs for this action.

Comment: If *browsing* is too broad and *clicking-through* too specific, then I'm afraid all you're left with is *go (from X to Y)*, which is what you just used, or *follow a link (from X to Y)*.

Comment: Should try SO where you can expect to find the current terminology for sort of things.

Comment: @ЯegDwight Geeks have a word for everything and in between - lol.

Comment: Importantly, your question is not consistent, if I read it right. Are you moving from one **page** to another or from one **site** to another? Tumblr and YouTube are two different sites, right?

Comment: *jump* is the word we use in my shop: jump away, jump back, jump from, jump  to. This works equally well between sites or between pages within a site.

Comment: @Kris If you go to a different site, you must be going to a different page. Like I can travel from one building to another, and I can travel from one city to another. If I say "I am going to another building", nothing about that sentence requires that it be in the same city.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: I meant websites.

Comment: @Jay When you move to another site, you say so; you don't say you are 'going to another page', which suggests a page on the same site.

Comment: Web-crawlers crawl from site to site

Comment: People are not crawlers. But in the late 90's "browse to" would have been a perfectly acceptable way to say "go from Yahoo.com to AOL.com", though it implied typing in the URL manually instead of clicking through a link.

Comment: @Alooe You say you want a _noun_ for an `action`. Is this correct?

Comment: Just wondering... Why you **need** this? Also wondering why nobody asked why before... :P

Comment: I don't understand the requirement for this being a noun?  What's an example sentence, please?

Answer (score 15):

Developers sometimes use the term *navigating*, which includes using bookmarks and the back and forth buttons.

Update:
If you don't like that (or *navigation* for the noun) how about *visit* as a verb meaning to go to some specified web site.

Comment: Navigating within a site; into a site; out of a site; yes. Between sites? Not sure.

Comment: You navigate within a site. +1 @Kris When you make a site, navigation is one of the critical things to consider in creation. It is a very awkward term to use for what OP is asking.

Comment: @Souta Your milage may vary. The people I talk to understand *navigate* to mean both within a site and between sites. Your comment did make me think of *visit*, which no one has suggested yet.

Comment: @gatkin I think we talk to different people then. ;) I like your suggestion of _visit_. It's a very simple suggestion, and I'm surprised no one thought of that until now.

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my list:

- **switch**
- **migrate** (too harsh and is rather used when, say, you change search engines)
- **Go** (ubiquitous and seems just right for any browsing activity)
- **hop** (as in : *site-hopping*) (this seems to fit in the context of the question)(can be used as a noun too, even as gerund)

Answer (score 1):

You can *load a page*, *open a page*, *bring up a page*, *browse to a page*, and so on. If needed, you can supplant the word *page* with *site*.

Answer (score 1):

You could say it is a *shift* from one page to the other. In this case, [*shift* means](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shift?s=t) "a change or transfer from one place, position, direction, person, etc., to another."

Or you could say this is *toggling* between pages or sites. In this case, [*toggle* means](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/toggle) "to switch to a different option, view, application, etc."

(Interestingly, in [psychological studies about *multitasking*,](http://www.apa.org/news/press/releases/2001/08/multitasking.aspx) both *shift* and *toggle* are used: *shifts of focus* and *toggle between tasks*.)

Answer (score 1):

I think "go" from one site to another is fine. It doesn't need to be complicated.

Just as if you were browsing in the high street you would "go" from one shop to another. You don't have to explain the act of walking :-)

Comment: Yeah, the verb is fine, but I need a noun :\ "Going" somehow doesn't sound right to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could say you are **surfing the web** or **browsing the web**

Answer (score 0):

Radio advertisers in my area seem to be using "click" lately, as in "click to www.something.com to buy our crap". Not sure I like it very much, but there is always a click involved, even if you find their site via search, so it's accurate, if somewhat over-broad.

Comment: For people who are too lazy to type "www." and ".com" (which are probably most) and use Google as a substitute for an address bar this is probably true.

Answer (score 0):

That is simply called 
[*surfing*](https://nmap.org/book/zenmap-topology.html). The mechanism of surfing is explained in the link.

Comment: Please include relevant information from behind the link in your post.

Comment: What information.. that also explains the method

Answer (score 0):

How about *transition*?

*Go*, *click*, *visit* and the like are all really nice straight-forward suggestions, but they don't really connote that you are coming from another site; it may as well be your first action in a given session of *surfing* or *navigating* the web, which is not the case described in your question.

*Shift*, as suggested by JLG, is also good in this sense, as are most of the answers given.

Comment: Please provide some authoritative sources that support your suggestion. :)

Comment: Ok, then. Here is one: https://www.asu.edu/purchasing/pdf/webmanual_0209.pdf

Comment: It says: "Make the transition from website to website as seamless as possible to ensure an optimal user experience."

Answer (score -1):

*paging,
tabbing (if your browser  supports tabs and you use them ).*